# SQL Select statement from multiple tables while adding values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out a good statement to write. I am able to achieve what I want when I query a specific 'Company' but I wanting to get the values for all of the companies in the database.

Basically I have 3 tables: Users, Companies, Plans_ExchangeMailbox. What I need to do is query how many plans are in use for each company. The plans are assigned at the user level in the users table.

Here is my table layouts:

**USERS**

DisplayName

CompanyCode (This is the ID from the CompanyCode in the Companies table)

MailboxPlan (This is the ID from the Plans_ExchangeMailbox Table)

**Companies**

CompanyName

CompanyCode

**Plans_ExchangeMailbox**

MailboxPlanName

MailboxPlanID

Here is the format I am looking to generate:
CompanyName, MailboxPlanName, Count (this is the number of MailboxPlanID for a company)

I was able to get this working but the problem is it can only do one company at a time and it doesn't get the CompanyName:

```
SELECT
Plans_ExchangeMailbox.MailboxPlanName,
SUM(CASE WHEN Users.MailboxPlan = Plans_ExchangeMailbox.MailboxPlanId THEN 1 ELSE 0      END) AS PlanCount
FROM
Plans_ExchangeMailbox, Users
WHERE
Users.CompanyCode='CC0'
GROUP BY 
Plans_ExchangeMailbox.MailboxPlanName
```

**The Final Format How it Should Be:**

Headers: CompanyName, PlanName, Count

Values:

Microsoft, Bronze Plan, 5

Microsoft, Gold Plan, 20

Dell, Bronze Plan, 3

Dell, Silver Plan, 80

etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
     C.CompanyName,
     E.MailboxPlanName,
     COUNT(1) Cnt
FROM Companies C
    JOIN Users U
       ON C.CompanyCode = U.CompanyCode
    JOIN Plans_ExchangeMailbox E
       ON U.MailboxPlan = E.MailboxPlanID
GROUP BY 
     C.CompanyCode,
     C.CompanyName,
     E.MailboxPlanID,
     E.MailboxPlanName
```

Grouped by  C.CompanyCode and E.MailboxPlanID in case if there are different companies or MailboxPlan with same name. If no,you can remove them from `GROUP BY clause`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! It looks like that is exactly what I need and is working great! I will add some more companies and users with that plan to make sure it all turns out right.